# Predicting size in memory of Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, memory-footprint

Is it somehow documented how much memory will exactly use a Dictionary in Swift, given the number of elements it will contain?

I have been looking for an answer, but all the information I found on the topic is vague. I also tried to figure it out by myself by reading Swift's source code, but that is too complex for me.

Comment: Take a look at `sizeOf`functions in the Swift Standard Library. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1539562-sizeof and the 'sizeOfValue`https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1539618-sizeofvalue

Comment: Thank you Adolfo. I already considered that, but those functions will not return the size of a Dictionary: even if Dictionary is defined as a struct, its storage is dynamically allocated, and therefore not considered by these functions. They will always return 8, which is the size of the pointer to that "backing" storage.

Comment: @George can you check my answer? It's working for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect the [declaration of `Dictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2568-L2572). It's a pretty big file, but after looking at it for a while, I believe the amount of bytes used by a dictionary follows these constraints:

```
bytes > (strideof(Key) + strideof(Value)) * 4/3 * capacity
bytes is a power of 2
```

I'm not 100% sure because it's hella difficult to understand the source without having written it myself. Have a look [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2568-L2572), [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2659-L2662), [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L250-L252) and [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2834-L2841). Probably it's possible to compile it yourself and put `prints` whenever the size changes, but I can't be bothered to do that. Why do you need the size of it?

Comment: Thank you for the guidance in reading the source code –yes, it's long! and difficult to understand for me, too; patience. 
I'd like to predict the size because I am planning data structures supporting some operations, where access time is very important but memory efficiency is also relevant. One approach I am considering involves the use of many "small" dictionaries; but if they use more memory than I want (which I suspect will happen) I will have to look for a better approach.

Comment: @George All data structures have a given access time and memory efficiency, for Dicts and Arrays, access is in O(1), memory usage is O(n), but an absolute value isn't available and may change if the implementation gets tweaked. Data structures don't take more memory than necessary though. I could help you more if you can tell me what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure, but after trying a few things I think you are correct.

Comment: What I am trying is long to explain. One of the points is encoding chess positions; both Piece and Square values are represented by 8-bit unsigned integers. Instinctively it feels natural to store this as Dictionary<Square: Piece>. But there are only 64 valid square values, and a maximum of 32 pieces on board, so if the structures created for a Dictionary of type <UInt8: UInt8> is big, then it would be a waste, since I will have many "almost-empty" dictionaries. In that case, I may use arrays. That's why I try to understand better how Dictionaries work.

Comment: @George Here is an idea: Use an array of `[UInt16]` to store the position of every piece, value is `0xffff` when the piece is not on the field, otherwise the first byte represents the column, second one the row. This way a single board always uses 32*2=64 bytes of memory. Probably you want your own `Position` that handles the getting and setting of the underlying `UInt16`. 64 bytes is very little memory, you can store over 15000 boards in 1MB.

Comment: @George It's always a tradeof between memory usage and efficiency: With this `[UInt16]` array you have low memory usage, but you need to scan the array to find which piece is on a certain position. Additionally to the piece array you can encode board as a 2-dimensional array of `[UInt8]`, which means you could also get the piece on a square fast, but takes up additional memory.